# org.si.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O err: Connection refused

Tags: spring

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for
>   "http://localhost:8081/FootballerShirt/footballerShirts": Connection
>   refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:525)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:473)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:238)
>     at
>   com.aucklanduni.spring.hibernate.HibernateFootballerShirtDaoMain.main(HibernateFootballerShirtDaoMain.java:44)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:510)
>     ... 3 more

Answer (score 0):

> for "http://localhost:8081/FootballerShirt/footballerShirts": Connection refused:

This simply means there is no server listening on port 8081 on localhost.